# PHP AJAX Interdependent Dropdown List not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an interdependent drop down list using AJAX and PHP. The problem is that whenever I change the menu in the first drop down list, it does not return the result from the while loop. However, it returns the other statement. To be clear lets discuss this over my codes.

HTML

```
<tr>
  <th class="col-sm-4">Category</th>
  <td>
    <select id="category" class="form-control">
      <?php while($c = $category->fetch()){ extract($c); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="col-sm-4">Board</th>
  <td>
    <select id="board" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select Board</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#category').change(function(){
    var dataString = {
      category: $('#category').val(),
      type: 'loadBoard'
    };
    if(dataString.category > 0){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'processes/settings.php',
        data: dataString,
        cache: true,
        success: function(html){
          $('#board').html(html);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

processes/settings.php

```
$category = (!empty($_POST['category']))?$_POST['category']:null;
$type = (!empty($_POST['type']))?$_POST['type']:null;

if($_POST){
  if($type == 'loadBoard'){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT brd_id, brd_title FROM forum_boards WHERE brd_cat = :cat");
    $stmt-> bindValue(':cat', $category);
    $stmt-> execute();
    $rc = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($rc > 0){
      while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ extract($row);
        echo "<option value=".$brd_id.">".$brd_name."</option>";
      }
    }else{
      echo $html = "<option value=''>No Board Exists</option>";
    }
  }
}
```

Here the problem is that when the condition `if($rc > 0){` is false it returns the `else` statement properly. That means it returns `No Board Exists` properly. But then the condition `if($rc > 0){` is true, it does not return the list under the while loop and my select box ends up blank. What is the issue here? Please help.

Comment: `PDOStatement::rowCount()` you is not reliable when it comes to select

Comment: Please AVOID `extract()` it is a horrible function that should not be used `<option value="<?php echo $c['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $c['cat_name;]; ?></option>`

Comment: I had to look it up, as I don't think I ever used it!

Comment: @RiggsFolly even then it doesn't solve my issue..

Comment: No it was not supposed to

Comment: then what should be done next?

Comment: As @MasivuyeCokile said .. [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) ...`If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications. `

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If @RiggsFolly can't solve the problem, he marks it as Duplicate. Great job.

Comment: by the way, it has nothing to do with `Row count with PDO` question. @RiggsFolly

Comment: No its a TYPO and should have been closed and deleted for that reason. But this reason is as good as any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change $brd_name to $brd_title

```
echo "<option value=".$brd_id.">".$brd_name."</option>";
echo "<option value=".$brd_id.">".$brd_title."</option>";
```

Comment: Oh Crap! I was using a wrong field name.. and it slipped below my eyes.. shit I wasted my useful hour behind this.. thanks mate for pointing it out!

Comment: For future reference TYPO's should not be answered, a simple comment and then a vote to CLOSE as a TYPO will suffice. This is because TYPO's are of no use to other.